# Is there a way to have same session for two web form apps in same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

Is it possible to have same session in two web form projects in same solution? I did find a something in [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27090/Sharing-Session-Across-Applications?fid=1422497&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=5743585&view=Normal&prof=True), but it doesn't work and it does not save the session data of one web form project to another project.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have some share session is to use a common database to save that session data there, manually - not using any kind of ready to use asp.net modules.

And you must also take care the cookie to been able to connect the same data to the users across the different sessions - or to use the login data of the two applications to make that share session...